# StoredProfileAWSCredentials complains it cannot find the profile in a Web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services

I am seeing the following error being returned when I run the `StoredProfileAWSCredentials` default constructor from within a web application:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentException: Path cannot be the empty string or all whitespace.
Parameter name: path
   at System.IO.Directory.GetParent(String path)
   at Amazon.Runtime.StoredProfileAWSCredentials.DetermineCredentialsFilePath(String profilesLocation) in d:\Jenkins\jobs\build-sdkandtools-release\workspace\sdk\src\AWSSDK_DotNet35\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs:line 354
   at Amazon.Runtime.StoredProfileAWSCredentials..ctor(String profileName, String profilesLocation) in d:\Jenkins\jobs\build-sdkandtools-release\workspace\sdk\src\AWSSDK_DotNet35\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs:line 300
   at Amazon.Runtime.StoredProfileAWSCredentials..ctor(String profileName) in d:\Jenkins\jobs\build-sdkandtools-release\workspace\sdk\src\AWSSDK_DotNet35\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs:line 270
   at Amazon.Runtime.StoredProfileAWSCredentials..ctor() in d:\Jenkins\jobs\build-sdkandtools-release\workspace\sdk\src\AWSSDK_DotNet35\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs:line 260
```

I am calling this method with no parameters.  I have a "default" profile defined which has worked when it has been used.   The web application is running under IIS 6.1 in an application pool which uses my credentials (since the AWS credentials were obtained under my login).

I have tried using the two-parameter constructor with the name "default" and the local disk path to the `RegisteredAccounts.json` file (which was generated for me by the AWS Toolkit extension for VS 2013).

What is happening here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the path in the Web.config file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="AWSProfilesLocation" value="path\to\RegisteredAccounts.json" />
    <add key="AWSProfileName" value="default"/>
    <add key="AWSRegion" value="us-west-2" />
</appSettings>
```

The credentials file should be in this format:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Another option is to include your keys directly in the web/app.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="AWSAccessKey" value="your key" />
    <add key="AWSSecretKey" value="your key"/>
</appSettings>
```

There are more details available in the [documentation](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/Tx1310VG2O81PSY/Referencing-Credentials-using-Profiles).

Comment: Trying that only changes the error a little.  Even if I include or exclude the actual RegisteredAccounts.json file in the key value.  I see then:

{System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentException: App.config does not contain credentials information. Either add the AWSAccessKey and AWSSecretKey or AWSProfileName.
   at Amazon.Runtime.StoredProfileAWSCredentials..ctor(String profileName, String profilesLocation) in d:\Jenkins\jobs\build-sdkandtools-release\workspace\sdk\src\AWSSDK_DotNet35\Amazon.Runtime\AWSCredentials.cs:line 318}

Comment: Is the credentials file in this format? 
[default]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: When I hand-generated the file with the "aws_access_key_id = " format, it works.   However, I am surprised that it worked before using just the RegisteredAccounts.json file.  Huh.

BTW, I do not need to specify the region as mentioned.  I do that elsewhere.

Comment: I think the auto-generated file is tied to the "SDK store" within Visual Studio. I haven't had any success getting that to work outside of running locally in debug mode, which is why I recommended the credentials file.

Comment: Instead of profile I'm suggesting to use AWS IAM roles in a deployed environment.

Comment: I put the root path to the file and it works! When I use a relative path didn´t work

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same issue, fortunately the source code is open on GitHub:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/tree/master/AWSSDK_DotNet35

When you use the SDK store, it tries to get the path of the RegisteredAccounts.json file with this code:
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + "/AWSToolkit"

In my local environment it pointed to my user profile, something like "C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\AWSToolkit"

But in the server it returned a blank string because I was using the Network User in the app pool, then I changed it for a local user in the server and even so the path was different from the one I've got before:
"C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\AWSToolkit"

Then I copied the .json file there, but didn't work until I logged in with the new user in the server and with the PowerShell tool of the SDK created a new file with the following command:
Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey  -SecretKey  -StoreAs

It created the file in the AppData located in the user folder, then I copied it to the path in system32.

And then it finally worked. Seems too cumbersome, but I really needed the credentials to be encrypted and when you use AWSProfilesLocation you have to store the UserAcessKey and UserSecretKey without any security in a plain text file.